# What's causing my WP7 app to crash?

Tags: silverlight, exception, windows-phone-7

I've had a few unexplained crashes happening on both the emulator and the phone itself.  Basically when my app crashes I get no dialog box whatsoever and the phone returns to the home screen.

I have the following code to display a MessageBox but this is somehow being bypassed...

```
// Code to execute if a navigation fails
private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString());
}

// Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
}
```

The thought occurred to me that it might be related to memory, since my app deals with a lot of images.  But I figure that would still be caught by my unhandled exception code above.  Any ideas on how I should track this down would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep an eye on your memory usage. An OutOfMemoryException crashes your app without calling the Application_UnhandledException handler.
You can check the current memory usage with some built in methods. I blogged about this a while ago http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2010/09/windows-phone-memory-constraints.html

Here's the basic code you should add:

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)};
timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
{
   var memuse = (long)DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("ApplicationPeakMemoryUsage");
   var maxmem = (long)DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceTotalMemory");
   memuse /= 1024 * 1024;
   maxmem /= 1024 * 1024;
   MyTextBlock.Text = String.Format("Mem usage: {0} / {1} MB", memuse, maxmem);
};
timer.Start();
```

Comment: I tried adding your code to my project and sure enough found it was consuming a massive amount of memory after continued use.  My app was using a little over 300 MB when it crashed.  I'm now looking into ways to cut back on the memory usage.

Comment: Ah ha.  I found the trick.  When disposing of images you must first set their source to null, then set the image itself to null for it to be picked up by garbage collection... `LargeImage.Source = null;  LargeImage = null;`  Thanks again.

Comment: I know it's long time, but this caught my attention. Wasn't it so that there was another active image reference, hence setting image=null couldn't help? Hard to believe that setting the Source to null would be required.

Comment: They do some caching internally. It looks stupid, but yes, it frees the cached object.

Answer (score 5):

A few things which have happened to me:

- If you're doing things on other threads, then IIRC exceptions on those threads will cause the app to just terminate. You may want to wrap the new thread code in an exception handler which propagates the exception to the UI thread
- If your app throws an exception before the first page is loaded, that can cause the app to just die without the appropriate handler being called
- If you've got a `StackOverflowException`, that can't be caught and will just make the app bomb

You may want to add some debug-build-only persistent logging (loaded and displayed within the app itself) to make it easier to work out how far the previous run of the application had got before crashing.

Comment: I have found threading to me a source of iritation in terms of exceptions causing the application to close. I would also recommend adding a debugging object or logger that you can attach that will make logs of what happened before the application crashed.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  It's strange how many exceptions aren't caught by the unhandled exception handler.  Hopefully Microsoft can fix that at some point.  Now at least I know what to look out for.  My particular problem seems to be due to an OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 1):

My app crashed in exactly the same way.

I tracked it down to throwing an OutOfMemoryException inside a DispatcherTimer tick handler, though the problem probably occurs elsewhere as well.

However, it is not the case that an OutOfMemoryException always takes down your program.  It does not.  I tried it in various other handlers, and it was correctly caught.

I've posted [a blog entry about lost exceptions here](http://wieser-software.blogspot.com/2011/12/lost-exceptions-inside-dispatchertimer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Could your app be being watchdoged for being unresponsive for too long? Perhaps due to the load time of lots of images and this code being executed on the UI thread.

Comment: The UI is responsive up until the crash occurs abruptly.  It appears to be a memory issue after all.

Comment: Ok cool, your limit is 90MB on devices with 256MB RAM. Beyond that, the memory is yours.